# How to make a jquery javascript library affect just a specific div in HTML?

Tags: jquery, html, version, javascript

I would like to know How to make a jquery javascript library affect just a specific div in HTML?. We suppose that we have the code below:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="jquery1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <div id="div1"></div>
    <div id="div2"></div>
</body>
```

We also suppose that the file jquery.js contains the jquery javascript library having the version 1.4: [version 1.4](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.js) and that the file jquery1.js contains the jquery javascript library having the version 1.11.1: [version 1.11.1](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js) . what I would like really to know is how can I make the jquery.js script affect just the div which has the id "div1" and how can I make the jquery1.js script affect just the other one (I mean the div having the id "div2"). Is it possible to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the end result you're trying to achieve? are you trying to use deprecated functionality from an older version of jQuery? You probably shouldn't load 2 different versions of jQuery on the same page.

Comment: Can I ask why? If you want IE suport just use 1.11.1 it has support for ie, 2.1.1 has no ie or legacy support.

Comment: This is not how we should work with jQuery

Answer (score 0):

`@Nick R` is right with his comment; you should not load different versions of `JQuery` on the same page. Different versions of the `JQuery` libraries often include different editions of the same functions and create conflicts with each other. This is because when an external file (`JQuery` library) is loaded into an `HTML` page, all of the `HTML` page has access to the file. So, when you load in two different libraries into the same page -- no matter where you are in the page -- everywhere will be aware of both libraries.


As a get around, you can create new pages that each load different libraries. Everything that you wanted to put inside the `div`s on the original page would be on the new pages. Then you would embed them into your original page as inline frames.

Comment: well, in fact I tried to put different parts in different HTML pages then to embed them in a page as you told me, but it didn't work..I had the same problem of Jquery libraries conflicts...By the way, have you ever work on Symfony2?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't say that I have worked on Symfony2. Can you be more specific in the way that it did not work?

Answer (score 0):

There are in fact "safe" ways of loading different versions of JQuery into the same page.
For example, if you are using the AngularJS framework, you can define $scope for both versions of JQuery.

Than you can scope various divs to a single version of JQuery in order to prevent any issues from occurring. In Angular, scoping is as simple as writing a controller which accesses JQuery. Than create $scope.jqv1 = .., and in the html

```
<div ng-controller="JQueryControllerOne">
```

etc.

Comment: well, in fact, I am working on Symofony2 framework, is it possible to do that in Symfony2?? if yes, will you please explain me how?..thanks in advance.